# When upgrading scipy, I came across Storing complete log in pip.log

Tags: python, scipy, gensim

I tried to install gensim for word2vec project and it stuck at the point like this:

```
----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/6t/wqrgwp2s5zv5tnyz3rh85mvh0000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6t/wqrgwp2s5zv5tnyz3rh85mvh0000gn/T/pip-IDV4D9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/6t/wqrgwp2s5zv5tnyz3rh85mvh0000gn/T/pip-build/scipy
Storing complete log in /Users/Myname/.pip/pip.log
```

And I did some research I realize it's sth wrong with the scipy. I tried to upgrade it (since I've installed long time ago) and it repetitively show this error. I tried "sudo" and install libblas-dev but still show this error.

```
   ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7Z45Gz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/scipy
Storing complete log in /Users/MyName/.pip/pip.log
```

I guess it's the same core problem essentially and I stuck here for long time.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Can you please post (relevant part of) the log?